How best to approach ML classification active learning loop with ratio data?
I am currently on a project trying to investigate structure-property relationships between molecules and their phase behaviour (which is binary in this case). The molecules have a backbone, any number of side chains and each side chain can have a range of lengths and flexibilities. So the data for any one molecule is a backbone length, 1D array of positions along the backbone where side chains are located, 1D array of the same length specifying side chain lengths, a value for how flexible the backbone is (10-100 in multiples of 10 from most to least flexible) and a final array to give the flexibility of each side chain. Note as well that there is dependence in the data i.e. if the backbone is longer the side chains can also be longer and there can be more of them.
I am trying to relate these features to my binary outcome but labelling is expensive so I'm doing pool-based active learning to get a good surrogate model with as little data as possible. The way I see it there are 2 options and I'm stuck on which would be best. Example data of one molecule in order of the above description:
10  [2,4,7]  [9,1,5]  100  [10,80,40]

I already know that geometrical descriptors I can calculate with a short simulation on each model correlate well with the target (simulation length around 30mins). To get these descriptors for the whole unlabelled pool is impossible because the total combinations of molecules if I vary the backbone length from 4 to 14 and allow all possible numbers, positions, bending and lengths of side chains would add up to millions. So I need to sample from the search space which is representative of the population and ideally end up with 2000 molecules or less. I am really quite unsure about how to do this because it's ratio data and I'm under the impression that traditional techniques like PCA won't handle it well. An additional problem is that I will need to oversample larger and more rigid molecules or I'll end up with an unbalanced class distribution. At the moment I'm trying to sample based on intuition for a well-rounded unlabelled pool which covers the main variability in molecule features but I'd like to know if there's anything more robust.

Skip the geometrical descriptors and have the surrogate model directly use the molecule features in the initial data. On the data I have random forest works well so that was the plan for the surrogate model, and I know it can handle categorical data well. But I think my data is in the incorrect format for it and if I one-hot encode I am worried about data sparsity. I have seen people suggest hashing but I need to be able to recover the molecule from the hashed data so I know what to simulate during labelling in the AL loop. One thing is that ideally I'd like to avoid unsupervised techniques like VAEs because I've had a lot of issues with reconstruction quality with these. Ideally there's some clever way I can transform the data (or even feature engineering which constructs combinations of the data) to input into the random forest.


If anyone has any comprehensive and implementable ways to achieve either of the goals above, that would be much appreciated. I'm currently using sklearn and ALiPy for the surrogate and AL loop.

Welcome to Cross Validated. Can you clarify a few thing ? What are the ratios of ? You say you are investigating  the  ”structure-property relationships between molecules and their phase behaviour” so what is your research question? It sounds like you want to do statistical inference, rather than prediction ?

@RobertLong Thanks for the response. I was referring to the type of data (which I think is confusingly named actually) which is like ordinal data but can be evenly spaced and 0 has a true meaning e.g. 0 side chain length means no side chains. The phase behaviour is just miscible in a solvent or immiscible (0 or 1). I need to relate the structure of the molecule to this i.e. how does flexibility or side chain spacing or lengths impact the class? A good RF model on a representative portion of the design space should allow me to do this. Labelling 1 or 0 is expensive, hence the active learning.
